# App that comfortably stream the audio output of macOS to an iOS device

Tags: audio, ios, iphone-app, macos, streaming

I’m looking for an application that:

- enables macOS to stream audio to an iOS device (like an iPhone or iPad)
- doesn’t require more than two clicks to enable/disable.
- does the jobs above and otherwise gets out of my way.

I am aware of Rogue Amoebas [Airfoil](https://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/), but it does not meet:

- the second requirement because of its demand to specify the app the audio output shall be streamed from.
- the third requirement as it has annoying mailing list popups.

EDIT: By audio I don't mean specific audio files or the audio output of specific applications, but the exact signal that would otherwise left my speakers.

Comment: Have you looked at VLC? See https://superuser.com/questions/625268/stream-video-from-vlc-on-desktop-to-vlc-for-ios